# Same declaration two different types

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I would like to be able to do this:

```
X<int> type_0;
X<int> type_1;
```

and I would like for type_0 and type_1 to be two different types. How can I do it?

Comment: You could... use different types? Or, am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean `typedef X<int> type_0;`?

Comment: @Mike and Kenny no guys, I want this class template (X) to be somehow declared that each instantiation with the same param creates new type.

Answer (score 7):

```
template < typename T, int I > class X; 

X<int, __LINE__ > x0; 
X<int, __LINE__ > x1;
```

x0 and x1 will be different types as will any other declarations like this if they are not on the same line in the file.

Comment: @CashCow it is in a way a solution but could you please explaint (for I don't know how;) what's the __LINE__ and what to do with this? Thank you.

Comment: nice :)  __LINE__ (with double underscores either side) is a preprocessor directive that represents the current line number in the code, so in a way this is similar to the ordinal approaches below but with kinda automated numbering

Comment: @CashCow I still have to provide manually __LINE__ so no go. But +1 for originality

Comment: @There_is_nothing_we_can_do Not if you use a macro

Comment: #define EXCLUSIVE_TEMPL(T1,T2) T1<T2,__LINE__> then EXCLUSIVE_TEMPL(X,int) x0; EXCLUSIVE_TEMPL(X,int) x1; on different lines

Comment: I gave a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255684/how-to-show-that-a-loop-control-variable-is-not-changed-inside-the-c-for-loop-b/4256336#4256336 only got +1 for it there though.

Comment: Just take care not to use this in a header, or you probably get different types in different including files xD

Answer (score 1):

You could use ordinal tags:

```
template <typename T, int Tag> class X { ... };

typedef X<int, 0> type_0;
typedef X<int, 1> type_1;
```

Alternatively, you could use inheritance:

```
class type_0 : X<int> { ... };
class type_1 : X<int> { ... };
```

But this suffers from some difficulties, such as the need to forward constructor parameters and hazards with mixing assignment semantics and inheritance.

Comment: @There...: Then the inheritance solution might be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parameterize on another thing (e.g. an integer?). For example, define `X` as `template <typename T, int N> struct X {...};` and use `X<int,0> type_0; X<int,1> type_1`. If template parameters match, they are the same type.

Comment: that's sort of the thing I want to do it with the difference only that I want this second param to be calculated by compiler so I do not have to manually type it

Comment: you mean you want every variable to be considered a different type? and you never want to refer to the type by name?

Comment: I want to be as you've said, every variable to be considered a different type.

Comment: then there is no construct to do T a, b; because by definition, a and b will have the same type. Cashcow's idea is good, then, using `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__` (non standard) or boost's preprocessor slot mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that inherits from the X template class, like this:

```
template <int I>
class type_i : public X<int>
   {
   };

typedef type_i<0> type_0;
typedef type_i<1> type_1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer +1, yes it sounds doable. I'll try on it now and later on I'll let everyone know how it went for me and what I've produced.