# Writing a macro

Tags: c++, macros

How to define a macro (this Q is somehow related to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275369/same-declaration-two-different-types) and CashCow's answer) which will expand to a different integer if this macro is used on different line in code?
I would like to be able to type:

```
X<1> _0;
X<1> _1;
```

after such def. I would like _0 and _1 to be of different types.

Comment: what's wrong with `__LINE__` mentioned in that question?

Comment: @kichik the problem with __LINE__ is that it is stated explicitly and according to CashCow it doesn't have to if a macro is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
#define var(T,...) T<__VA_ARGS__,__LINE__>
```

or if your only doing this for one know type:

```
#define var(x) T<(x),__LINE__>
```

I suggest using `__COUNTER__` instead of `__LINE__` however, it allows the type to be globaly
unique, not just unique to the line.

EDIT: reread the question, what exactly do you mean by "different integer"? as in a different type or different initialization value?

```
template<typename T = int, const T nValue> class Integer
{
    T Value;
    Integer() : Value(nValue)
    {
    }

    operator T()
    {
        return Value;
    }
};

#define VI(x) Integer<__COUNTER__> x
```

or (This seems to be the one you want)

```
#define I(x) int x(__COUNTER__)
```

Comment: @Necrolis thanks for this __COUNTER__ it is safer than __LINE__

Comment: @There, @Necrolis `__COUNTER__` is not standard, whereas `__LINE__` is

Comment: @Armen: as of GCC 4.3 its supported, and MSVC was the compiler introducing it, that covers a lot of ground, so it almost is standard :P

Comment: @Armen I use VS and they support it so it's fine with me.

Comment: @Necrolis by different int I've meant different value;

Comment: @Armen: its a pity it isn't standardized, `__COUNTER__` has soooo many uses @There: see my final macro then, it'll construct an `int` with a different value each time

Comment: I am soo sceptical about heavy preprocessor use... and introducing things like `__COUNTER__` somewhat encourages people to use macros

Comment: @Armen IMHO it is impossible to write fully portable code except the simplest and tutorial ish examples. And as about 90% of soft for Win is written in VS I personally think that there is no harm in using it.

Comment: @Armen well, preprocessor is for to be used. Guys from Boost are using it all the time.

Comment: @Armen: be skeptical about poor/improper/down-right horrible cpp use, clever cpp has some wonderful uses, like compile time binary obfuscation(for which `__COUNTER__` is used)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you want, but it's pretty close.

```
#define X(arg) Y<(arg), __LINE__>

X(1) _0;
X(1) _1; // different type than previous line
```